# I want to create and manipulate a property array in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to create and manipulate a property array in Neo4j. I am new to both Graph Database and Neo4j. I am building a membership graph database with a subscription component. I need the member to relate to a LEDGER node with an array property for each month of subscription paid. I know I can create a node for each payment made...but I am trying to neatly assign the member subscription to one node. From what I understand so far I cannot have a Key/Value pair in the Array Property...but can I assign the values to the property array with:

SET Ledger.AmtPaid[index]=amt
or something similar...I get errors when I try this:

```
CREATE (m:Member {name: "Michael"})
CREATE (l:Ledger {name: "Member Ledger", AmtPaid :[]})
CREATE (m)-[:PAID_INTO]->(l)

MATCH (m {name:"Michael"})--(l)
SET l.AmtPaid[0]="50"
Return l.AmtPaid[0];
```

Comment: Sounds like a problem for a relational database

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to use labels and rel-types in your query

Unfortunately writing to an index doesn't work as Cypher treats its collections as immutable.

You can either do:

```
MATCH (m:Member {name:"Michael"})-[:PAID_INTO]->(l)
SET l.AmtPaid = ["50"] + l.AmtPaid[1..]
Return l.AmtPaid[0];

or

MATCH (m:Member {name:"Michael"})-[:PAID_INTO]->(l)
SET l.AmtPaid = l.AmtPaid + ["50"]
Return l.AmtPaid[0];

or

MATCH (m:Member {name:"Michael"})-[:PAID_INTO]->(l)
SET l.AmtPaid = 
   reduce(a=[], idx in range(0,size(l.AmtPaid) | 
          a + case idx when 0 then ["50"] else [l.AmtPaid[idx]] end)
Return l.AmtPaid[0];
```

Comment: Michael thanks for the response. However none of these options provide an answer. Also, are you then saying that we cannot manipulate arrays in Neo4j or just Cypher? Can this be done in Java?